# Formalism of the modern theory of polarization of a solid

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

I am reading the book chapter

> Theory of Polarization: A Modern Approach. Raffaele Resta and David Vanderbilt. In [*Physics of Ferroelectrics: A Modern Perspective*](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-34591-6), K.M. Rabe, C.H. Ahn and J.-M. Triscone (eds), Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2007. [Author eprint](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~dhv/pubs/local_preprint/dv_fchap.pdf).

and on page 12 they are talking about Formalism of Theory in continuous $k$-space.

They are considering crystalline system with lattice periodic potential which has Bloch form eigenfunctions $\psi_{nk}(r)=e^{ik.r}u_{nk}(r)$ where $u_{nk}$ is periodicity of lattice potential and obeys the Schrödinger equation 
$$
H|\psi_{nk}\rangle=E_{nk}|\psi_{nk}\rangle 
\quad \text{with} \quad 
H=p^2/2m+V
$$
or equivalently $H|u_{nk}\rangle=E_{nk}|u_{nk}\rangle$ where (equ.14)
$$H=\frac{(p+\hbar k)^2}{2m}+V$$
in which all quantities depend on adiabatic parameter $\lambda$. Further they are using first order adiabatic perturbation theory and wrote first-order correction which is (eq. 15):
$$|\delta\psi_{nk}\rangle=-i\hbar \dot\lambda\sum_{m\ne n} \frac{\langle\psi_{mk}|\partial_\lambda \psi_{nk}\rangle}{E_{nk}-E_{mk}}|\psi_{mk}\rangle$$
where $\dot\lambda=d\lambda/dt$. So far so good.

After this they wrote first-order current in equation 16 which I don't understand. They find
$$j_n=\frac{dP_n}{dt}=\frac{i\hbar e\dot\lambda}{(2\pi)^3 m}\sum_{m\ne n} \int dk\frac{\langle\psi_{nk}|p| \psi_{mk}\rangle \langle \psi_{mk}| \partial_\lambda \psi_{nk}\rangle}{E_{nk}-E_{mk}}+c.c.$$
**Can anyone explain this how they get this result?**

Then in eq. 17 they are changing $dP/dt $ to $dP/d\lambda$ and applying perturbation theory of eq. 14 to get following results:
$$\frac{dP_n}{d\lambda}=\frac{ie}{(2\pi)^3}\int dk \langle\nabla_k u_{nk}|\partial_ku_{nk}\rangle+c.c$$
**How do they come to this one?**

Comment: What exactly is $P_n$ here?

Comment: Polarization of n-th band.

Comment: Ok, but what is the definition the authors use ? When $P$ depends on $t$ through $\lambda$ only, one can switch easily from $dP/dt$ to $dP/d\lambda$.